# Problem with inserting data in Oracle database using PHP

Tags: php, oracle, ora-00911

The following error:

> "Warning: oci_execute()
>   [function.oci-execute]:    ORA-00911:
>   invalid character in
>   F:\wamp\www\SEarch Engine\test1.php 
>   on line 69"

is being generated by this code:

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
$db = oci_new_connect(ORAUSER,ORAPASS,"localhost/XE");

$url_name = $_POST['textfield'];
$keyword_name = $_POST['textarea'];
$url_type = $_POST['RadioGroup1'];
$anchor_text = $_POST['textfield2'];
$description = $_POST['textarea2'];   

$sql = "select seq_url1.nextval seq_url1 from dual"; 
$result = oci_parse($db,$sql);

oci_execute($result);   
if($result) 
{
    while($row = oci_fetch_array($result))
    {   
        $temp = $row['SEQ_URL1'];
        echo $temp;
    }
}           

$sql_url1 = 'INSERT INTO URL1(Url_ID,Url_Name,url_Type,Anchor_Text,Dscription) '.'VALUES($temp,:url,:type,:anchor,:description)';

$compiled = oci_parse($db, $sql_url1);

oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':url', $url_name);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':type', $url_Type);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':anchor', $anchor_text);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':description', $description);

oci_execute($compiled);
?>
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Well, can you show us the invalid character and what the queries look like when they are sent to the database?

Comment: I'm not Oracle Guru, but why do you have a period between your Fields and your VALUES statement where you define $sql_url1?

Comment: @George - that period is the PHP concatenation operator in this case... as for *why* it's there, I am curious as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be caused by the misspelling of "Description":

```
$sql_url1='INSERT INTO URL1(Url_ID,Url_Name,url_Type,Anchor_Text,Dscription)...
                                                                  ^ here
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$sql_url1 = 'INSERT INTO URL1
                (Url_ID,Url_Name,url_Type,Anchor_Text,Dscription)'.'
             VALUES
                ($temp,:url,:type,:anchor,:description)';
```

...should be:

```
$sql_url1 = 'INSERT INTO URL1
                (Url_ID,Url_Name,url_Type,Anchor_Text,Dscription)'.'
             VALUES
                (seq_url1.NEXTVAL,:url,:type,:anchor,:description)';
```

You don't need two queries to perform the operation, just call the sequence.NEXTVAL within the INSERT statement.  The only reason to use what you've got, is if you are re-using that sequence value for other records.

Also, it's possible that `Dscription` is a typo, that doesn't match the actual column name.  Confirm by using `DESCRIBE URL1`.  And you could try printing the query prior to it being run:

```
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':url', $url_name);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':type', $url_Type);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':anchor', $anchor_text);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':description', $description);

echo $sql_url1
```

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is that the encoding of your web form, and the encoding of your Oracle database and/or connection don't match. mySQL will gracefully write the broken character into the table - maybe Oracle is more strict.

But first check whether George Johnston's or John Rasch's observations are not already right on the money, and provide us with some debug data to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a poorly used PHP variable in your query.

```
$sql_url1 = 'INSERT INTO URL1(Url_ID,Url_Name,url_Type,Anchor_Text,Dscription) VALUES($temp,:url,:type,:anchor,:description)';
```

In here, $temp is intended to just dump the integer, but since the string uses single quotes no substitution takes place and oracle sees "$temp" (which isn't valid in that context). Switch to double quotes:

```
$sql_url1 = "INSERT INTO URL1(Url_ID,Url_Name,url_Type,Anchor_Text,Dscription) VALUES($temp,:url,:type,:anchor,:description)";
```

Or take the above suggestion and use `seq_url1.nextval`. Description is misspelt, but that will throw an unknown column error, not an invalid character error.

Thanks,
Joe